# full-screen code block/banner (squarespace)

Tags: javascript, squarespace, p5.js

I am in the process of developing a portfolio website. My existing website is poorly formatted and designed and I would like to move over to squarespace, however I am struggling to inject my p5.js sketches into squarespace.

In my [existing website](http://lockedsgn.com/home2.html) I have placed a p5.js sketch behind my title. This is achieved by coding the script to span the width of the page and dynamically resize. My title text is styled in CSS to appear in front of the script with it's z-index. (simple right?)

In my new [squarespace site](https://aiden-locke-th3p.squarespace.com), I would like to create the same effect, by choosing "advanced" when editing the banner content, and the inserting the code for the script under "page header code injection", as well as embedding a link to the p5.js library. When I do this I end up with a white screen and no animation.

tl;dr moving my bootstrap site to squarespace, can't inject a p5.js script into my banner.

Comment: I don't know anything about squarespace. But how is the banner content injected? Is it part of the original page source, or is it added using ajax? If it's added using ajax, you need to actually call the library, since it won't happen automatically.

Comment: @KevinWorkman I can't be sure, like I said my knowledge in this area is lacking. I'm relatively certain the template I'm working with does not use ajax, but inserts whatever code I type into the form into the source code. Regardless I'm hoping for an answer specific to working with squarespace, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're injecting your p5.js script into the code injection area of the page instead of the index. It's just a caveat of Squarespace that code has to be injected into the index rather than any of the individual pages in the index.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the animation in the CSS of the website. You can do do this by > website > website tools > custom css ( for sqs 7.1 )

Maybe get the ID of the block you’d like to animate through the Google square space id searcher ( only available to use on Google and include it in the link )